# Название приложение на разных устройствах не одно и то же

Tags: android, android-studio

вот манифест созданного приложения или первого модуля приложения, не знаю как правильно сказать:

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".MainMenu">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Как видите `android:label="@string/app_name"` задан и такой строковый ресурс есть.

Потом я добавил библиотеку Android-File-Dialog и подключил её как модуль. 
вот манифест этого модуля

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.lamerman"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.lamerman.FileDialog" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Если я устанавливаю приложение на эмуляторе , там у меня андроид 4.4 что ли, то название приложения то которое я задал. Если устанавливаю через usb на свой с андроид 5.1 , то название приложения как в этом модуле. 
 Как правильно устанавливать название в таком случае ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас два файла манифеста, а в итоге должен получиться только один. Отсюда и конфликты.

В **Android Studio** при открытии файла манифеста внизу есть вкладка **Merged Manifest** на которой можно увидеть результат слияния манифестов и получить информацию о конфликтах.

Comment: не должен быть он один, в проекте у каждого модуля свой манифест, по ссылке которую мне дали в комментарии написано, что есть специальные правила объединения манифестов, т.е. в процессе компиляции все манифесты сливаются в один.

Comment: @Turalllb, вы правы, я поправил ответ.